# нужно написать программу через def. в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Создайте функцию, которая принимает 2 целых числа. По системе координат `x` и `y`, где `x` -  первое вводимое число, `y` - второе вводимое число. Ваша задача написать функцию, где пользователь вводит два числа 5 раз и надо определить, где находится ваша текущая позиция. Старт дан с координатами `(0, 0)`.
> Формат ввода 2 числа. Формат вывода список из 2 аргументов.

Пример ввода:

> ```
> 1 1    2 3    4 3    5 10    7 15
> ```

Результат:

> ```
> [19, 32]
> ```

мое решение без функции:

```
first = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 1 координаты x и y ').split()]
second = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 2 координаты x и y ').split()]
third = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 3 координаты x и y ').split()]
fourth = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 4 координаты x и y ').split()]
fifth= [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 5 координаты x и y ').split()]
coor_x = first[0] + second[0] + third[0] + fourth[0] + fifth[0]
coor_y = first[1] + second[1] + third[1] + fourth[1] + fifth[1]
print(coor_x, coor_y)
```

Comment: На этом форуме не решают вашу задачу. А помогают решать. Начните делать. Будут проблемы, спрашивайте. Хотите полное решение? это к фрилансерам.

Comment: решение есть, но не могу его в функцию добавить

Comment: ну так опубликуйте код

Comment: @Manul74 Это _**НЕ**_ форум.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы переделал ваш код с помощью цикла и списков:

```
list_ = [] 
for i in range(1, 6):
    list_.append([int(num) for num in input(f'Введите значения {i} координаты x и y ').split()])

cord_x, cord_y = 0, 0
for x, y in list_:
    cord_x += x
    cord_y += y
```

А потом переделал бы в функцию:

```
def f(cord, x, y):
    cord[0] += x
    cord[1] += y
    return cord

cord = [0, 0]
for i in range(1, 6):
    cord = f(cord, *[int(num) for num in input(f'Введите значения {i} координаты x и y ').split()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Очень простой способ сделать из решения без функции решение с функцией:

```
def reshenie():
    first = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 1 координаты x и y ').split()]
    second = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 2 координаты x и y ').split()] 
    third = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 3 координаты x и y ').split()] 
    fourth = [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 4 координаты x и y ').split()] 
    fifth= [int(i) for i in input('Введите значения 5 координаты x и y ').split()] 
    coor_x = first[0] + second[0] + third[0] + fourth[0] + fifth[0]
    coor_y = first[1] + second[1] + third[1] + fourth[1] + fifth[1] 
    print(coor_x, coor_y)

reshenie()
```